# fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database - Visual Studio 2003

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

I get this error: `fatal error LNK1201: error writing to program database` every time I edit my code and build again in visual studio 2003.

The issue is resolved if I restart VS2003 but I need to do this every time i build the project.

I have been googling and stackoverflowing ;) for a few hours and have tried the following proposed solution:

1. Change the Debug Information Format from Zi to Z7. (**Property -> C/C++ -> General -> Debug Information Format**)

   *This did not work*
2. Change Visual Studio Compatibility Mode to Windows XP SP3

   *This did not work*
3. Add the following in the Pre-Build Event : `net stop "Machine Debug Manager"
   net start "Machine Debug Manager"`

   This produced the following error: `System Error 5 has occurred. Access is denied.` This could be because **I do not have Admin Access** on this machine.
4. I have not tried this one because I am not allowed to download untrusted code at my work. Run FreePDB.cmd posted by Tony76 [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0271379-3ab1-4e08-af9e-d4f51fe8de79/lnk1201-error-at-every-build?forum=vclanguage)
5. Changed the Symbol Path as seen here: [image]

   *This did not work*

**What I know:**

This error could occur if the pdb file exceeds 1GB but mine is only 10MB.

**My limitations:**

1. I do not have Admin Access on this computer
2. Cannot run untrusted software (Work Computer)

Comment: This happens to me (somewhat frequently) when my projects/solutions are on a network share and/or I don't have write access ... have you tried [changing your symbol path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) ..?

Comment: I have not. I will try this right away

Comment: Did not work, thanks for trying

Comment: Aggressive anti-malware is by far the most common cause of this problem.  If you can't do anything about it then you're kinda screwed.  Pass this off to whomever is responsible for keeping the machines inside the company running.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem when I was moving my VS project from old disk to new PC. Deleting all debug files eliminated the issue, maybe Clean-Build would solve it as well, but that is not what I have tried.

Comment: Deleting the `.pdb` file mentioned in the error worked for me.

Comment: Clean + Build works too.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue in VS2017. Deleting the PDB mentionned in the error solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called LockHunter to unlock the PDB file.  This works, though from time-to-time if stops successfully unlocking (or recognizing that the PDB file is locked) and I have to restart my PC

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem on Windows 10. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648650/) provides a solution using a tool called `FreePDB`. Worked for VS2003.NET, but apparently this solution works for multiple versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues when the solution was open in both VS2017 and VS2013. Fixed this issue by closing both the visual studio instances and re-opened the solution file.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for some cases, close all msbuilds and running instances, some prior run may crashed and holding the some files/pdb